# Is it possible to loop to sum values in lists within nested dictionaries?

Tags: python

my data structure is the following:

```
all= {
        'part1': {'act1': [0, 0], 'act2': [100, 0]},
        'part2': {'act1': [25, 1], 'act2': [100, 1]}, 
        'part3': {'act1': [25, 0], 'act2': [0, 1]}, 
        'part4': {'act1': [0, 0], 'act2': [0, 1]}
        }
```

My goal is to get the global sum of all the first items in the lists.

So far I have only managed to get the sum for each key of the top level dictionary, with this code:

```
for partData in all.values():
    depPart = 0
    for act in partData.keys():
        depPart += partData[act][0]   
    print(depPart)
```

It returns

```
100
125
25
0
```

while I would like to get the sum i.e. 250

Every attempt I have made to loop further in order to get this sum has resulted in errors.

Is looping the way to do it, if yes how? Or is there another / a better way to get to it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that firstly

```
for partData in all.values():
    depPart = 0
    for act in partData.keys():
        depPart += partData[act][0]   
    print(depPart)
```

on line 2 `depPart=0` each time you get a value from all   `print(depPart)` prints value everytime it sums every value inside each value so your code should have been

```
depPart = 0
for partData in all.values():
    for act in partData.keys():
        depPart += partData[act][0]   
print(depPart)
```

hope it helps

Comment: There may be some error while copying code . I personally ran the code and got answer of 250 only

Comment: It does, thank you! And it uses loops to do it, so good to know it is possible to do so.

Comment: Well no problem

Comment: Yes, my bad, I did not see at first that the print line was deindented. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `sum` function with a generator expression that iterates through the values of the dict and the sub-dicts:

```
sum(n for d in a.values() for n, _ in d.values())
```

This returns:

```
250
```

Note that `all` is a built-in function name, so I've renamed the `all` variable in your question to `a` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfect. I'm beginning with python and i am not yet familiar with the sum function, I will further dig into it. Regarding the use of "all", duly noted, ty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension with `sum`:

```
d = {'part1': {'act1': [0, 0], 'act2': [100, 0]}, 'part2': {'act1': [25, 1], 'act2': [100, 1]}, 'part3': {'act1': [25, 0], 'act2': [0, 1]}, 'part4': {'act1': [0, 0], 'act2': [0, 1]}}
_sum = sum(sum(a for a, *_ in c.values()) for c in d.values())
```

Output:

```
#[100, 125, 25, 0]
250
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist This solution does not use `zip`. Can you clarify?

Comment: I'm on mobile and the first draft said zip. I see you've edited since then.

Comment: Thanks, it works as well as blhsing's answer, so now I know two ways of doing it ;-)